# unable to use a code for import table from latex csv

Tags: excel

[image]Hi All I am using this code to import my Table1.csv file , but yet unsuccessful please help me which parts to edit thanks a lot:

```
%        File: essai_datatool.tex
%     Created: mer jui 01 09:00  2009 C
% Last Change: mer jui 01 09:00  2009 C
%
%Facteur de magnification : 1000 signifie ``multiplié par 1'' 
\mag=1000

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,xfor,substr}
\usepackage{eurosym,datatool,longtable}
\textwidth=16cm
\textheight 24cm
\oddsidemargin -10mm
\topmargin -15mm
\pagestyle{empty}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\input{epsf.sty}
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,%
keys={Temperature,Time,T2G},%
headers={\shortstack{Incubation\\Temperature},%
\shortstack{Incubation\\Time},\shortstack{Time to\\Growth}}%
]{t2g}{Table1.csv}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Time to Growth Data}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\centering
\DTLdisplaydb{Table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Any error messages in particular we should look out for? Could you provide a few lines of the CSV? Nobody can easily answer as is.

Comment: The first time I ever tried to import a csv file into latex I was greatly helped by this question:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66504/pdfplotstable-longtable-with-caption-and-repeating-header worked first time after modifying to reflect the columns of my particular table.  Without your table or at least the header can't do much else.

Comment: Thank you very much , the table I have is pretty small , just two rows, one parameter, the other one is the numbers , I tried the 3rd code in the line EngBIRD has shared , thank you , but it only imports everything stuck together , no space and no table design

Comment: I also just added the table in the way I wanted to be

Comment: Can you give us the csv-file in plain text? Hard to reproduce some output without knowing the input ;-)

Comment: Are there any news here?