# “Continued on next page” in longtable environment part 2

Tags: longtable, pgfplotstable

I am attempting to get the effect of the table to show "continued on next page" and "concluded" like that shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66504/pgfplotstable-longtable-with-caption-and-repeating-header).

I am calling a `longtable` saved in the data.dat file (given below).  Can you assist me in getting the last line of the table to shop like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,
header=true,
columns={theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y},      % display specified columns
columns/theta1/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r,column name={$\theta_1$}},
columns/r2v/.style={column type=l,precision=6,dec sep align,column name={$r_{2v}$}},
columns/r3v/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r,column name={$r_{3v}$}},
columns/x/.style={column type=l,precision=5,dec sep align,column name={$x$}},
columns/y/.style={column type=l,precision=5,dec sep align,column name={$y$}},
% requires booktabs to place horiz rules
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule\endhead},
every last row/.style={after row=
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{2}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }%
    %
]{data.dat}

    \end{document}
```

Here is the data.dat file:

```
theta1    r2v    r3v      x      y
73.32513 0.08109 0.32216 1.07136 1.58646
81.52127 0.39714 0.18930 1.12726 1.54498
11.42881 0.15561 0.40579 2.00083 -0.25418
82.20383 0.26427 0.26641 0.98759 1.65272
56.91233 0.08282 0.17536 1.39728 1.09515
8.77864 0.30099 0.46950 2.07209 -0.48038
25.06484 0.13149 0.43797 2.02329 0.26017
49.21934 0.32704 0.27508 1.78136 0.81424
86.17562 0.34461 0.31124 0.95389 1.75653
86.83997 0.37408 0.29352 0.96191 1.74816
14.18518 0.22527 0.10387 1.73510 -0.29920
87.35335 0.04191 0.15062 0.60779 1.62930
86.14503 0.11449 0.23546 0.72013 1.69588
43.68381 0.45667 0.11524 1.82554 0.43447
72.02524 0.07619 0.42215 1.13327 1.65837
12.76977 0.41291 0.09738 1.76232 -0.52640
37.95852 0.26917 0.11296 1.74265 0.39662
82.41620 0.49807 0.08535 1.18931 1.44604
71.29866 0.03909 0.11383 1.02021 1.36372
86.35432 0.22134 0.21785 0.81945 1.67413
59.01666 0.05333 0.15555 1.32064 1.14392
3.21405 0.48095 0.46169 2.01803 -0.85916
76.42164 0.00232 0.21510 0.88239 1.55644
84.05939 0.38746 0.09241 1.03807 1.49802
61.08616 0.40865 0.45244 1.73304 1.27895
68.19661 0.43435 0.48987 1.59916 1.50884
66.88192 0.04222 0.21943 1.16654 1.37700
35.30043 0.19989 0.05556 1.67229 0.33875
58.99301 0.12994 0.12903 1.37311 1.08118
15.40680 0.40003 0.20436 1.88439 -0.40392
63.54415 0.21571 0.29745 1.43481 1.29929
2.86496 0.45532 0.13111 1.68131 -0.86237
24.92307 0.09092 0.30142 1.88300 0.23440
4.15543 0.13190 0.35561 1.90078 -0.48544
8.74186 0.07277 0.11087 1.68263 -0.31065
74.11120 0.06803 0.05871 0.96481 1.35119
62.53458 0.43465 0.14834 1.58297 1.04053
28.53895 0.28985 0.15939 1.83473 0.11008
85.51998 0.27493 0.21208 0.89672 1.65209
3.10015 0.07248 0.25393 1.78677 -0.46653
39.48699 0.42652 0.04276 1.77733 0.27689
34.34026 0.31103 0.13124 1.80291 0.26160
68.89651 0.17548 0.40051 1.30693 1.53810
71.56799 0.25662 0.01461 1.18879 1.20559
16.81853 0.20090 0.46443 2.08509 -0.09151
44.07880 0.03798 0.36517 1.71079 0.92168
```

Comment: Solution to your problem: [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276485/dec-sep-align-from-pgfplot-does-not-align-with-the-header-properly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed your given code to solve the problem with the table head and foot of `longtable` in `pgfplotstable`. I kicked out the styling of the columns, to give it to you as homework (please read the documentation of `pgfplotstable`!).

To get rid of the first line (see result later) you can add an `empty header`.  Please follow the advices in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66504/pgfplotstable-longtable-with-caption-and-repeating-header?lq=1).

The complete MWE (including `.dat` file with package `filecontents`; see that I added some data after line `0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0`; marked changings with `% <======`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
theta1    r2v    r3v      x      y
73.32513 0.08109 0.32216 1.07136 1.58646
81.52127 0.39714 0.18930 1.12726 1.54498
11.42881 0.15561 0.40579 2.00083 -0.25418
82.20383 0.26427 0.26641 0.98759 1.65272
56.91233 0.08282 0.17536 1.39728 1.09515
8.77864 0.30099 0.46950 2.07209 -0.48038
25.06484 0.13149 0.43797 2.02329 0.26017
49.21934 0.32704 0.27508 1.78136 0.81424
86.17562 0.34461 0.31124 0.95389 1.75653
86.83997 0.37408 0.29352 0.96191 1.74816
14.18518 0.22527 0.10387 1.73510 -0.29920
87.35335 0.04191 0.15062 0.60779 1.62930
86.14503 0.11449 0.23546 0.72013 1.69588
43.68381 0.45667 0.11524 1.82554 0.43447
72.02524 0.07619 0.42215 1.13327 1.65837
12.76977 0.41291 0.09738 1.76232 -0.52640
37.95852 0.26917 0.11296 1.74265 0.39662
82.41620 0.49807 0.08535 1.18931 1.44604
71.29866 0.03909 0.11383 1.02021 1.36372
86.35432 0.22134 0.21785 0.81945 1.67413
59.01666 0.05333 0.15555 1.32064 1.14392
3.21405 0.48095 0.46169 2.01803 -0.85916
76.42164 0.00232 0.21510 0.88239 1.55644
84.05939 0.38746 0.09241 1.03807 1.49802
61.08616 0.40865 0.45244 1.73304 1.27895
68.19661 0.43435 0.48987 1.59916 1.50884
66.88192 0.04222 0.21943 1.16654 1.37700
35.30043 0.19989 0.05556 1.67229 0.33875
58.99301 0.12994 0.12903 1.37311 1.08118
15.40680 0.40003 0.20436 1.88439 -0.40392
63.54415 0.21571 0.29745 1.43481 1.29929
2.86496 0.45532 0.13111 1.68131 -0.86237
24.92307 0.09092 0.30142 1.88300 0.23440
4.15543 0.13190 0.35561 1.90078 -0.48544
8.74186 0.07277 0.11087 1.68263 -0.31065
74.11120 0.06803 0.05871 0.96481 1.35119
62.53458 0.43465 0.14834 1.58297 1.04053
28.53895 0.28985 0.15939 1.83473 0.11008
85.51998 0.27493 0.21208 0.89672 1.65209
3.10015 0.07248 0.25393 1.78677 -0.46653
39.48699 0.42652 0.04276 1.77733 0.27689
34.34026 0.31103 0.13124 1.80291 0.26160
68.89651 0.17548 0.40051 1.30693 1.53810
71.56799 0.25662 0.01461 1.18879 1.20559
16.81853 0.20090 0.46443 2.08509 -0.09151
44.07880 0.03798 0.36517 1.71079 0.92168
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
76.42164 0.00232 0.21510 0.88239 1.55644
84.05939 0.38746 0.09241 1.03807 1.49802
61.08616 0.40865 0.45244 1.73304 1.27895
68.19661 0.43435 0.48987 1.59916 1.50884
66.88192 0.04222 0.21943 1.16654 1.37700
35.30043 0.19989 0.05556 1.67229 0.33875
58.99301 0.12994 0.12903 1.37311 1.08118
15.40680 0.40003 0.20436 1.88439 -0.40392
63.54415 0.21571 0.29745 1.43481 1.29929
2.86496 0.45532 0.13111 1.68131 -0.86237
24.92307 0.09092 0.30142 1.88300 0.23440
4.15543 0.13190 0.35561 1.90078 -0.48544
8.74186 0.07277 0.11087 1.68263 -0.31065
74.11120 0.06803 0.05871 0.96481 1.35119
62.53458 0.43465 0.14834 1.58297 1.04053
28.53895 0.28985 0.15939 1.83473 0.11008
85.51998 0.27493 0.21208 0.89672 1.65209
3.10015 0.07248 0.25393 1.78677 -0.46653
39.48699 0.42652 0.04276 1.77733 0.27689
34.34026 0.31103 0.13124 1.80291 0.26160
68.89651 0.17548 0.40051 1.30693 1.53810
71.56799 0.25662 0.01461 1.18879 1.20559
16.81853 0.20090 0.46443 2.08509 -0.09151
44.07880 0.03798 0.36517 1.71079 0.92168
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} % <===========================================

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
col sep=space,
%columns={theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y},      % display specified columns
%columns/theta1/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r,
%columns/r2v/.style={column type=l,precision=6,dec sep align,
%columns/r3v/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r,
%columns/x/.style={column type=l,precision=5,dec sep align,
%columns/y/.style={column type=l,precision=5,dec sep align,
% requires booktabs to place horiz rules
every first row/.style={before row={% <=================================
  \caption{This is a Table with Data}%
  \label{tab:DataTable}\\
  \toprule 
  \textbf{theta1} & \textbf{r2v} & \textbf{r3v} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\ 
  \toprule    
\endfirsthead % <=======================================================
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
  \toprule
  \textbf{theta1} & \textbf{r2v} & \textbf{r3v} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\ 
  \midrule
\endhead % <============================================================
  \midrule \multicolumn{5}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
\endfoot % <============================================================
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{5}{r}{{End of table}} \\ \bottomrule
\endlastfoot % <========================================================
}}%
]{\jobname.dat}

\end{document}
```

and the result (first page):

[image: first page]

and the second page:

[image: second page]

With some changes on the first code of mine you can get the alignment you asked in the comment.  Why I have to use `&&` instead of `&` in the definition of the header I can't say. I guess that needs some deeper research in the code how the header is builded.  Perhaps a question to the package maintainer ...

In the following MWE I leave out the `filecontents` part (copy it from the first code please) and see the marked changes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} % <===========================================

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} % <==================================================
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
%outfile={testtable.tex} % to check the resulting table code
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
header=has colnames,        % true|false|has colnames 
col sep=space,
columns={theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y},      % display specified columns
columns/theta1/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,column type=r,column name={$\theta_1$}},
columns/r2v/.style={column type=l,precision=6,dec sep align,column name={$r_{2v}$}},
columns/r3v/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,column type=r,column name={$r_{3v}$}},
columns/x/.style={column type=l,precision=5,dec sep align,column name={$x$}},
columns/y/.style={column type=l,precision=5,dec sep align,column name={$y$}},
% requires booktabs to place horiz rules
every head row/.style={output empty row}, % <===========================
every head row/.append style={before row={% <===========================
  \caption{The caption}\label{tab:DataTable}\\%
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{theta1}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{r2v}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{r3v}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{x}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{y}} \\ 
  \midrule
\endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{theta1}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{r2v}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{r3v}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{x}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{y}} \\ 
  \midrule
\endhead
\midrule \multicolumn{5}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
\endfoot % <============================================================
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{5}{r}{{End of table}} \\ \bottomrule
\endlastfoot % <========================================================
},
}%
]{\jobname.dat}

\end{document}
```

with the resulting pages 1:

[image]

and page 2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I seem to still have an issue with the number formatting.   I looked at the documentation and included `columns/theta1/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=5},` for example.  But when I put the command `dec sep align`, the header no longer lines up properly.  I tried the command `columns/theta1/.style={dec sep align,fixed zerofill,precision=5},` but I lose the header alignment.  Can you offer some more insights as to how I can get the numbers to show up with precision= 5 and aligned with the decimal point?  Thanks.